# Private Google Access for cross project bucket access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-networking

Does [Google private access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access) allow access to Google Storage bucket available in a different project (cross-project access)? We would like to access the Google bucket without an external IP attached to the machine (and possibly without NAT as the dataset we have is huge).

Answer (score 1):

Referencing to your query, for accessing the Cloud Storage Bucket without External IP:

1) If you are accessing from the GCP project through [Google APIs for domains](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config-domain) restricted.googleapis.com or private.googleapis.com then you need to configure DNS such that VMs in your VPC network resolve requests to *.googleapis.com and *.gcr.io using the set of IP addresses associated with the chosen domain.

2) If you are accessing [outside of GCP projects ( on prem )](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga-onprem) then by configuring the Cloud VPN or Cloud Interconnect by connecting to Google APIs and services by using the virtual IP addresses (VIPs)

Answer (score 1):

I created a Google VM instance with only internal IP address on my default subnet with private access on. I was not able to reach the internet from my VM but I could access cloud Google Cloud Storage with gsutil, and also was able to download a blob with wget. From my understanding, from the documentation and from my tests the trafic path from my instance to Google APis remains within Google's network. If you have shared VPC to different project then you can perform the same from another project too.

Answer (score 0):

Google private access allows access to the Cloud Storage service (as a whole). Which buckets and objects you can access from there depends on the permissions given to the calling code. From example, if you call Cloud Storage with the Compute Engine's default service account credentials, you'll be able to access buckets and objects that [allow access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) to that service account, whichever project they're in.